# Static declaration issue in YII with parent

Tags: php, yii, static-methods

Suppose I have this classes

```
<?php
class Grandparent {
    public function myMethod($param) {
        //do something
    }
}
class Parent extends Grandparent {
    public function myMethod($param) {
        //do something
        return parent::myMethod($param) ;
    }
}
class Son extents Parent {
    public function myMethod($param) {
        //do something
        //code to access parent parent
    }
}
?>
```

I want in myMethod of Son class to avoid call his parent and access to this grandparent. The code I tried was parent::parent::myMethod($param) but and the Ide throws me an error. Which is the way to access in a static way to grandparent with out passing through parent?

Is there any posibilities? I know there are some methods like get_parent_class, but I dont want them to use it. I need to call in static way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.inheritance.php

```
<?php
class foo
{
  public function something()
  {
    echo __CLASS__; // foo
    var_dump($this);
  }
}

class foo_bar extends foo
{
  public function something()
  {
    echo __CLASS__; // foo_bar
    var_dump($this);
  }
}

class foo_bar_baz extends foo_bar
{
  public function something()
  {
    echo __CLASS__; // foo_bar_baz
    var_dump($this);
  }

  public function call()
  {
    echo self::something(); // self
    echo parent::something(); // parent
    echo foo::something(); // grandparent
  }
}

error_reporting(-1);

$obj = new foo_bar_baz();
$obj->call();

// Output similar to:
// foo_bar_baz
// object(foo_bar_baz)[1]
// foo_bar
// object(foo_bar_baz)[1]
// foo
// object(foo_bar_baz)[1]

?>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. Is that what I need. I never try to use class_name::method thinking that the method isnt static, but If I think, parent::method is not static too.